# Autowired annotation not working in DAO classes. Using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, spring-java-config

I am trying to build a simple registration and login using Spring framework 5. And I am trying to avoid xml configuration by implementing java config classes. I don't want to use hibernate yet because i would like to learn to make it work with spring jdbc first before i use the easy but advance hibernate. I have tried to load database credentials from property file.

I am getting this exception after i submit registration form.

I have tried to display the errors using println method and logger but it is not showing for some reason I need to figure out. So here are two things

1. Not able to find exactly what is creating NullpointerException because it says it is nested Exception. I think it is database connection which is causing this problem and I am confused why I am not having SQLDriver Class not found exception if it is database connection.
2. Why am i not able to display output of variables causing null exception and Why is my logger implementation not displaying any details of errors.

I have tried various methods to solve it but wasted long time due to failure to make it work. Hence, I am here for expert's help.

I think something is not going well with how i tried to load database credentials to make database connection works as datasource is still null i guess hence i would like to know 
How to load database credential from property file using java config class (not xml approach) and use it in DAO?

**database-properties.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorstudentdb1
jdbc.user=webadmin
jdbc.pass=Password1
```

**DispatcherConfig class**

```
package com.rabin.tutorstudent.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

    public class DispatcherConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

            return new Class[] {PersistanceConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

            return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {

            return new String[] {"/"};
        }

    }
```

**PersistanceConfig class**

```
package com.rabin.tutorstudent.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:database-properties.properties"})
@ComponentScan({"com.rabin.tutorstudent"})
public class PersistanceConfig {
    //env
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;
        @Bean
        public  DataSource dataSource() {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

            return dataSource;
        }
}
```

**SpringConfig class**

```
package com.rabin.tutorstudent.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
//@ComponentScan({"com.rabin.tutorstudent"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:database-properties.properties"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages= "com.rabin.tutorstudent")
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;

    }


}
```

**UserDAOImpl**

```
package com.rabin.tutorstudent.daoimpl;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.rabin.tutorstudent.dao.UserDAO;
import com.rabin.tutorstudent.model.User;

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    public final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /*
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        System.out.print(dataSource);
    }
    */
    public void save(User user)  {
        String query = "insert into user (username, password, firstname, lastname, email, role) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        logger.debug(query);

        Connection con = null;
        logger.debug("Connection Initialization "+con);
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            logger.debug("Datasource value=" +dataSource);
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            logger.info("Connection to db"+con);
            System.out.println("Connection :"+con);


            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            //ps.setLong(parameterIndex, x);
            ps.setString(1, user.getUsername());
            ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            ps.setString(3, user.getFirstName());
            ps.setString(4, user.getLastName());
            ps.setString(5, user.getEmail());
            ps.setString(6, user.getRole());
            int out = ps.executeUpdate();

            if(out !=0){
                System.out.println("Employee saved with id="+user.getId());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Employee save failed with id="+user.getId());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Sql error" +e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public User getById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public List<User> getAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**UserDAO**

```
package com.rabin.tutorstudent.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.rabin.tutorstudent.model.User;

public interface UserDAO {

    //Create - insert
    public void save(User user);

    //Read - select
    public User getById(Long id);

    //Update - change
    public void update(User user);
    //Delete - Remove
    public void deleteById(Long id);
    // Get All
    public List<User> getAll();
}
```

**SignUpController**

```
package com.rabin.tutorstudent.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


import com.rabin.tutorstudent.daoimpl.UserDAOImpl;
import com.rabin.tutorstudent.model.User;


@Controller
public class SignUpController {
    public final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SignUpController.class);
    @Autowired
    // sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signUp() {
        return "register";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView signUpPost(
            @RequestParam("username") String username,
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            @RequestParam("firstname") String firstname,
            @RequestParam("lastname") String lastname,
            @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("role") String role) {
        logger.debug("Inside signUpPost method.");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        logger.info("Model view ="+mv);
        User user = new User(username, password, email, firstname, lastname, role);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setFirstName(firstname);
        user.setLastName(lastname);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setRole(role);
        //dao call
        UserDAOImpl uDAO = new UserDAOImpl();
        //UserDAO uDAO = new UserDAO();

        //User u = new User(username, password, email, firstname, lastname, role);
        //uDAO.insertUser(u);
        uDAO.save(user);
        System.out.println("User Registered..");
        return mv;



    }
}
```

**User**

```
package com.rabin.tutorstudent.model;

public class User {
private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String role;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(Long id, String username, String password, String email, String firstName, String lastName,
            String role) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
    }


    public User(String username, String password, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String role) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


}
```

And here is my console output giving me nested NullpointerException.

```
Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.38
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Server built:          Feb 5 2019 11:42:42 UTC
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Server number:         8.5.38.0
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: OS Version:            10.0
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Architecture:          amd64
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_152-b16
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\G3\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\G3\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.5.38
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\G3\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\G3\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.5.38
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\G3\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\G3\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.5.38\endorsed
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
        INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_152/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_152/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_152/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\G3\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\G3\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\G3\Desktop;;.]
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
        INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
        INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
        INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
        INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
        INFO: Initialization processed in 702 ms
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
        INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
        INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.38
        SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
        SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
        SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:06 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
        INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
        INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
        INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
        INFO: Server startup in 5279 ms
        Feb 28, 2019 5:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/tutorstudent] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.rabin.tutorstudent.daoimpl.UserDAOImpl.save(UserDAOImpl.java:41)
            at com.rabin.tutorstudent.controller.SignUpController.signUpPost(SignUpController.java:53)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Output on browser**

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:986)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


Root Cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.rabin.tutorstudent.daoimpl.UserDAOImpl.save(UserDAOImpl.java:41)
    com.rabin.tutorstudent.controller.SignUpController.signUpPost(SignUpController.java:53)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with Data source initialization, It's picking up the values from the property file as there are no errors at the time of initialization, but, it's that the @Auotwired doesn't work in DAOImpl. probably because you are not using `@component` annotation. Spring doesn't know that it has to Autowire  `data source` in DAOImpl.

Also, why not Autowire `UserDAO` in `SignUpController` You are taking the DI in your hand and expecting Spring to Autowire something for you. If you are planning to instantiate the object yourself then you should also set the Datasource.
I'd recommend you refer to some samples to make this easy.

Comment: Thank You. I just added @component annotation as you have directed but the dataSource is still null and not able to get connection.

Comment: That would be because of 'UserDAOImpl uDAO = new UserDAOImpl();' since you are instantiating the Implementation object yourself you need to set the data source as well. If you autowire userDAO in your controller then it becomes springs job to inject the data source dependency in the UserDAOImpl.